# Buffer Octet Stream in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am novice in NodeJs and i have read about `Buffer` but not clear.

Some examples:-

```
1) var buffer = new Buffer(12);
2) var buffer = new Buffer([12,54,89]);
3) var buffer = new Buffer("Confusing about Buffer", "utf-8");
```

Here my queries are,

- What is the Buffer and what is the way to define/implement.
- What is meaning of above examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In javascript, strings are not binary safe. There are certain characters that are illegal in strings.

This of course makes it very difficult to process binary data such as images or mp3 files since all I/O in javascript deal with strings.

The solution that the node developers implemented is Buffers. Think of buffers as strings for binary data (and remember, text is a subset of binary data).

As for your specific questions, the answer to your second question answers your first question: *the example code you posted are examples of how to define buffers*.

Comment: @Purag: The first couple of sentences basically paraphrases the description from node itself: "Pure JavaScript is Unicode friendly but not nice to binary data." from https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html. Though I have to admit that I didn't test the example.

Comment: @robertklep: Hmm.. removing that example.

Comment: I see. I feel like there's a critical piece of this answer missing. It just seems incomplete. I feel like leading with "strings are not binary safe" is not quite good.